# IOS search tag name completion bubble

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm trying to create a search bar with a name auto complete that looks something like this in the image.

[image: autocomplete text bubble]

Does anyone have an idea how I may be able to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking solely about the programming aspect or also about the graphics? If only about the programming, see my below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`TTMessageController`](http://api.Three20.info/interface_t_t_message_controller.php) and the [`TTMessageRecipientField`](http://api.Three20.info/interface_t_t_message_recipient_field.php) from the open source library [Three20](http://three20.info/). It's just what you want:

[image: TTMessageController example]

Answer (score 0):

First you need an array with the contact's names:

```
//Add Address Book framework    

#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>

--------------------

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *allPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

NSMutableArray *firstNames = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSUInteger personIndex = 0; personIndex <= [allPeople count]; personIndex++){

    ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[allPeople objectAtIndex: incrementer];

    firstNameString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    [firstNames addObject: firstNameString];
}
```

So the `firstNames` array now contains an array of all the people;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) 
{
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(your, values, go, here) reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.text = [firstNames objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

}
```

So far, you have a tableview with all the first names. Make sure you implement the other required methods in the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Also make sure that you declare the `firstNames` array a property in your header file to make sure it is accessible throughout the .m file, because if you do not do that, then you cannot access it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

To implement autocompletion, follow Ray Wenderlich's tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values) on custom autocompletion values. Then use the array of peoples' first names as the custom values.